# Kubernetes Cluster: How to figure out which nodes are master nodes

Tags: kubernetes

When I use the command kubectl get nodes. I got list of nodes with ROLES . Are there any way I can find out which nodes are masters?

Comment: What output you got after running `kubectl get nodes`? Usually the node with master role are the master one.

Comment: It seems that you are running your cluster in some cloud provider, otherwise the `ROLES` would have master for the node which is the master. I know that for EKS (for instance) you actually don't have access to the master node, it's all managed by AWS in the background. You could add that type of information on your question to make it more complete and get a proper answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this command for this purpose.

```
kubectl get node --selector='node-role.kubernetes.io/master'
```

Comment: The cluster is created by eks.
`
kubectl get nodes
NAME                                        STATUS   ROLES    AGE        VERSION
ip-10-07-8-33.us-west-2.compute.internal    Ready    <none>   28d    v1.14.9-eks-49202c
ip-10-07-98-31.us-west-2.compute.internal   Ready    <none>   34d    v1.14.9-eks-f459c0
`

Comment: `
It does not work.
kubectl get nodes --selector='node-role.kubernetes.io/master'
No resources found in default namespace.

kubectl get nodes --selector='node-role.kubernetes.io/master' -n kube-system
No resources found in kube-system namespace.

kubectl get nodes --selector='node-role.kubernetes.io/master' --all-namespaces
No resources found
`

Answer (score 3):

In EKS, according to the [AWS Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/clusters.html):

> The control plane runs in an account managed by AWS, and the Kubernetes API is exposed via the Amazon EKS endpoint associated with your cluster.

As mentioned in my comment above, you don't have access to the master node in an EKS cluster, as it is managed by AWS.

The idea behind it is to "make your life easier" and make you worry only about the loads that will run on the worker nodes.

There is also [this documentation page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/what-is-eks.html), that may help in the understanding of EKS.